# Does Ninject support multi injection and factory methods simultaneously?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Ninject supports multi injection:

```
public class Samurai 
{
    public Samurai(IWeapon[] allWeapons) 
    {
        var allWeapons = allWeapons;
    }
}
```

It also suppport automatically generated factories:

```
public class Samurai 
{
    public Samurai(Func<IWeapon> weaponFactory) 
    {
        var weapon = weaponFactory.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Somehow it doesn't handle both features combined:

```
public class Samurai 
{
    public Samurai(Func<IWeapon>[] weaponFactories) 
    {
        var weapons = weaponFactories.Select(factory => factory.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Results with:

```
Error activating IntPtr
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
```

Is there a way to accomplish that or do I have to implement factories manually?

Comment: Try changing it to `Func<IWeapon[]>`.

Comment: @Steven: Doesn't work as well

Comment: It was worth a try :)

Comment: And what if you inject an `IEnumerable<IWeapon>`? Perhaps Ninject returns a new instance every time you iterate the collection. (just thinking out load here).

Comment: Wow, this actually yields the new instance every time! Thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @MiłoszWierzbicki, I tried Steven's first suggestion (`Func<IWeapon[]>`) and it works. I am curious why it didn't work for you.  Can you include how you register your weapon classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the constructor to:

```
public Samurai(IEnumerable<IWeapon> weaponFactories)
```

`IEnumerables` yield a a new instance every time you iterate the collection (in case the lifestyle is transient). So in a sense an `IEnumerable` is factory (it behaves as a stream).